# how to define global queryset object which i can use in my django views

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I want to define global variable which stores data from database table for particular filter in that model. I need that data in every view functions defined. I don't want to fire a query every time when my function calls, if there is ajax calls i can reuse that object.If page refresh, then i will make query again but on the same page if any ajax call has been made, i can reuse the same global variable without firing DB Query.
I am using django framework for this.
Any suggestion on this how can i optimize this solution?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use context_processors for this:
Note: Context_processor always returns dictionary only

For example:

context_processors.py

```
def global_data(req):
   your_global_query = YourModel.objects.all()
   return {'queryset':queryset}
```

Now you need to add this function in your settings.py file

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {

        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
             ..........
            'your.path.to.global_data'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! but for every web request there is some filter in my model. Sorry, i forgot to mention. So when my page refresh, then i can understand i need to fire a DB query, but if i have a ajax call on the same view function, then is there any way to solve this?